# How would I change displayed text in HTML Angular?

Tags: html, angular, text

I do have 6 tabs displayed in my Angular template:

```
 <tabset class="tabs">
      <tab *ngFor="let option of options" [heading]="option.type" >
      <!-- tab content -->
 </tab>
```

The **heading** of each tab is read in a quite *ugly format*, from a JSON data( the six values are :
*NEW, SUMMARY, CURRENT, EXPIRED, ARTICLE, EXTRA*).

I would like to be able to pretty print these strings. For example, to change:

'*EXPIRED*' -> '*Expired Section*'

or

'*SUMMARY*' -> '*Summary Calculation*'

How can I do that?

Comment: create a pipe or a format function, [heading]="yourFormatFn(option.type)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that does your trick:

```
public myFormats = {
   EXPIRED: 'Expired Section',
   ....
}

public getMyFormat(type){
   return this.myFormats[type];
}
```

```
<tabset class="tabs">
      <tab *ngFor="let option of options" [heading]="getMyFormat(option.type)" >
      <!-- tab content -->
 </tab>
```

Credits to [mr.void](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7404235/mr-void)

Comment: A pipe would be better as the values will be cached and it's easier to reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create an object with your mapping

In Your TS:

```js
const mapping = {
       'EXPIRED': 'Expired Section',
       'SUMMARY':'Summary Calculation'
};
```

In your HTML:

```html
 <tabset class="tabs">
      <tab *ngFor="let option of options" [heading]="mapping[option.type]" >
      <!-- tab content -->
 </tab>
```